# How to add Unity Touchscreen function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New to making games in Unity and I've tried to use every way possible to find the answer for this.

How would I add a touch screen function to this C# code in unity to make the player move left and right?

### My code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rigi;
    private Animator anim; 

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool isFacingRight = true;

    public float maxSpeed = 7.0f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayers;

    private float groundCheckRadius = 0.2f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigi = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = this.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        try
        {
            float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rigi.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 
            (move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            this.anim.SetFloat("Speed",Mathf.Abs(move));

            if((move > 0.0f && isFacingRight == false) ||  
            (move < 0.0f        && isFacingRight == true))
                {
                Flip ();
            }
        }
        catch(UnityException error)
        {
            Debug.LogError(error.ToString());
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;                     
        Vector3 playerScale = transform.localScale;         
        playerScale.x = playerScale.x * -1;                 
        transform.localScale = playerScale;                 
    }
}
```

Comment: And **what exactly** is your problem?

Comment: [TouchScript](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7394) Pretty efficient, even if documentation is crap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Input.touches to detect the screen touch.

Maybe in this case you should detect if the player is pressing the right/left side of the screen and moving it accordingly. You can do that by comparing the touch position, something like input.touches[0].position.x < Screen.width/2 to move right for example.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html

Just a piece of advice, do not use GetComponent inside the update method. In this case you don't actually need it because you already have the references on the awake method.